# auto-refreshing iframe in div still refreshes when DIV is hidden jquery classic asp

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a DIV with an IFRAME that I hide (the div, not the iframe). The iFrame continues to refresh despite being hidden. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').find('iframe').attr('src','');
```

This stops the iframe loading anything. Post some of your code and explain why the iframe is refreshing. You shouldn't need iframes for most cases, tell us what functionality you're trying to create.

Comment: That works. I have a legacy app that refreshes a "chat window" that the users all like and I haven't had time to remove it.

Comment: Ah. If you decide to keep the chat, see if you can use AJAX, it'll be much easier to stop and restart the requests :)